# Isomorphism of R-modules

Tags: modules, abstract-algebra

Does somebody has an example where the left $R$-modules $R^m$ and $R^n$ are isomorphic for all positive integers $m$, and $n$?

Comment: Is $R = \{0\}$ allowed? If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, then this is not possible.

Comment: R={0} is not allowed.(thanks anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)$ denote the ring of "[column finite matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Infinite_matrices)", where $R$ is some ring.. Then, one can show that $\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)\to\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)^2$ defined by

$$M\mapsto (\text{odd indexed columns of }M,\text{even indexed columns of }M)$$

is an isomorphism of $\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)$-modules. It clearly then follows that $\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)^m\cong\mathrm{CFM}_\mathbb{N}(R)^n$ for all $n$ and $m$.

I believe this example is in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: Thank you ! Is very usefull for me this example.

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to see this as the endomorphism ring of an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ and using an isomorphism $V\cong V\oplus V$. It's the same, but without matrices that introduce the need of proving the ring axioms.

Comment: @egreg As you pointed out, this is literally the same ring though :)

Comment: 100% agree with egreg.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Now kiss :)

Comment: About what you are saying I am thinking that the construction of the isomorphism from V must be taking coordinates in a basis .So I think working with the matrix version  That Alex gave is also quickly.