# if $K=L$ then $K'\cong L'$. Furthermore, if $H$ is submodule of $M$ and $K$ is submodule of $H$ then $H=K\oplus\left(H\cap K'\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Let $M$ be $R$-module and $K,K',L,L'$ be submodules of $M$ with the property that $M=K\oplus K'=L\oplus L'$. Prove that if $K=L$ then $K'\cong L'$. Furthermore, if $H$ is submodule of $M$ and $K$ is submodule of $H$ then $H=K\oplus\left(H\cap K'\right)$

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: suppose $K\oplus K'=K\oplus L'$ then $K'\cong (K\oplus K')/K=(K\oplus L')/K\cong L$.

Second thing: by [distributivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580873/sum-and-intersection-of-submodules/581083#581083) you get $H=(K+ K')\cap H=(K\cap H)+ (K'\cap H)=K+(K'\cap H)$. Notice that $K\cap (K'\cap H)\subset K\cap K'=0$ so $H=K\oplus(K'\cap H)$.

Comment: +1 vote :) I want to know, if we only suppose $K\cong L$, can conclude $K'\cong L'$?

Comment: No this wont be true. Its important in the proof that I m dividing by the same module not isomorphic ones.

Comment: Can we have a counterexample?

Comment: For example there are some noncommutative rings with the property that $R=R\oplus R$ as modules but ofc we can write $0\oplus R=R\oplus R$ and it would mean that $R\cong 0$ with is silly.

Comment: Example of such ring simpliest as far as i know http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570217/isomorphism-of-r-modules

Comment: Much simpler example $\bigoplus_\mathbb Z\mathbb Z\oplus 0\cong  \bigoplus_\mathbb Z\mathbb Z\oplus \bigoplus_\mathbb Z\mathbb Z$

Comment: Ehm... If $K\cap L=0$, can conclude that $K+L$ is direct summand of $M$?